# Converting a time into 12 hour format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i convert `24` hour formatted time into `12` hour formatted time in SQL server 2008?

Comment: Why not convert it in the code instead of the db?

Comment: @OrWeinberger, we aren't sure there is any other code as the question only mentions SQL, perhaps it could be a report.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you have the current time in a variable/column of type time? If so, it's easy:

```
declare @t time
set @t = '14:40'

select CONVERT(varchar(15),@t,100)
```

result:

```
2:40PM
```

If it's in a `datetime(2)` variable, then you'll have to strip out the date portion after running the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). If it's in a string, then first `CONVERT` it to `time`, then use the above code.

Comment: Why convert the time to a string? This is probably not a good idea in most circumstances.

Comment: @dportas - if it's heading into a client application, then I agree, it'd be better to let that application do the formatting. On the other hand, if it's a query that's defining (say) an export to a CSV file (and whatever boneheaded system that wants this CSV wants AM/PM instead of an ISO formatted datetime value), then I don't see the harm. And since we care about format, we have to convert to a string.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you need to do it inline:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),  CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100) as AmPmTime
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to rAdmin's comment, the syntax is:

```
CONVERT(data_type,expression,style_code)
```

Here are some other style codes you can use:

```
SELECT
GETDATE() AS GetDate,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),0) AS '0',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100) AS '100',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),1) AS '1',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101) AS '101',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),7) AS '7',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),107) AS '107',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108) AS '108',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108) AS '108',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),10) AS '10',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),110) AS '110',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),12) AS '12',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) AS '112',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),14) AS '14',
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),114) AS '114'
```

Tried to post an image of the result set, but I need to "Earn more than 10 reputation to post images".

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Right(IsNull(Convert(Varchar,GetDate(),100),''),7)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL can perform inline conversion for time

mytime in database is 4:15:00

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),  CAST(mytime AS TIME), 100) as my_time from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't format the time. It's your client application that controls how the time is displayed. You should change the time format settings in your application or your code.

Comment: As an application, it should store in a general date like UTC and the client to convert that date back into a date relatable to the client.