# How to convert time to hh:mm:ss tt in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert time to format like `01:05:33 PM` which is saved in database like `13:05:33`. What should be the query for that. I want to get `12 hour format` basically. In the database it may be saved in `24 hr`. It's only `time` field.

I have used `FORMAT` function but it gives error that `FORMAT()` function is not valid.

Comment: SQL Server's formatting functions are quite limited. If possible, you should try to format data in your client application rather than in the SQL query itself.

Comment: SQL Server stores `time` in binary format without formatting.  The T_SQL `FORMAT` function was introduced in SQL Server 2012 to more easily convert the value to a formatted string but it is better to format data for presentation purposes in the presentation layer rather than in SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a time into 12 hour format in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745527/converting-a-time-into-12-hour-format-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

The full help on CAST and CONVERT functions is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx):

Using your specific example, this should work:

```
DECLARE @testTime time;

SET @testTime = '13:05:33';

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), @testTime, 130);
```

Comment: Put in wrong last number, sorry. Editing main result.

Comment: Changed 3rd argument to 130: this will give you milliseconds but will provide the 12 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Convert`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx) function with *style* `109`

```
declare @time time ='13:05:33'
select convert(varchar(20),@time,109)
```

**Result :** `1:05:33.0000000PM`

**Note:** [**`FORMAT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function is introduced in `SQL SERVER 2012`