# SQL Server Compact Edition 12 hour time format

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

Been searching anywhere but I cant find any solution to my problem. I am working with SQL Server Compact Edition, Im using SQL Management Studio 2008 and dealing with time formats.

I want a datetime datatype returns a 12hour format. So far, I have this one:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(10), StartTime, 108) as timein
FROM TicketSales
```

It gives this result : 14:43:05

How can I achieve a 12 Hour format for this ? any help please?
Note: For SQL Server Compact Edition 2008

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If one of the answers below helped you, you should mark it correct.  This is an expectation of any user who asks a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come to an answer uses format mask 109:

```
SELECT
    GETDATE() AS timestamp,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(26), GETDATE(), 109), 14) AS time;
```

[image]

If you don't want those fractional seconds, then we can try using substring and concatenation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(26), GETDATE(), 109) AS time
)

SELECT
    time,
    SUBSTRING(time, 13, 8) + RIGHT(time, 2) AS time
FROM cte;
```

[image]

Comment: How about removing the seconds in there ?

Comment: Use `SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar(26), GETDATE(), 100), 7) AS time` ... but this isn't the output your question seemed to be asking for, so I didn't address this in my answer.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You must use the right style, like 100

```
declare @mytime as Time = '14:00'
select CONVERT(varchar(15),@mytime,100)

=> 2:00pm
```

Original Answer:
[converting-a-time-into-12-hour-format-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745527/converting-a-time-into-12-hour-format-in-sql)

Comment: If you think the question is an exact duplicate, then you should vote to close it, rather than answering it.

Comment: i cant, not enough rep :-)