# Best way to change 24hr time to 12hr time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I currently have a field, IncidentTime, that's displaying time in a 24 hour format. For example, 16:30:00:0000000. How can I convert this field to display the time as "4:30 PM"?

Comment: If greater than 12 subtract 12

Comment: What is the data type of `IncidentTime`?

Comment: @GordanLindoff the datatype is TIME.

Comment: The `time` data type doesn't have a format, it's a binary value. This should be somethi g your presentation layer should be doing, not the SQL.

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745527/converting-a-time-into-12-hour-format-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can `convert()`. Assuming that your column is of `time` datatype:

```
select convert(varchar(8), mycol, 100) formatted_col from mytable
```

Else, you might need to `convert()` to a time first:

```
select convert(varchar(8), convert(time, '16:30:00'), 100) formatted_col from mytable
```

Comment: this is actually working for one of my time fields. The other one is having the "M" cut off for 2-digit hours. Example: 11:00P. Also,how I can add the seconds, so I get a result of 8:00:00 AM or 11:00:00 PM? Thanks.

Comment: Correction: this is working for all fields with TIME. One was set to VARCHAR(6). However, if I could get the seconds too, that would be great.

Comment: @DPool34: `109` gives you the seconds and microseconds.